# How can an arbitrarily nested Django model (like a directory structure) be specified?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django web app, I wish to create something like a directory structure using Django objects.

In other words, the goal is to construct a Django model (say a model defined as `Box`) that can contain (or simply be associated with) an arbitrary number of other `Box` objects, along with an arbitrary number of `Thing` objects. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Even better: is it possible to design the `Box` model to contain (or simply be associated with) even more objects, in addition to `Thing`, i.e. `Gadget`, `Item`, etc.?

Comment: Perhaps a many-to-many field will be a good approach [Django many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a tree structure for the boxes, achieved with a self referencing foreign key and a different class, maybe abstract, that represents Things inside the box for example:

```
class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_box = models.ForeignKey("Box", on_delete=PROTECT, null=True, related_name='children_boxes')

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    box = models.ForeignKey(Box, on_delete=PROTECT, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s')

    class Meta:
         abstract=True

class Gadget(Thing):
    gadget_field = models.CharField(max_length=400)

class Item(Thing):
    item_field = models.CharField(max_length=600)
```

Comment: Self referencing foreign key for Box was exactly what I was looking for! Just for follow up: is it necessary for Thing to be abstract? What do we lose if Thing isn't abstract?

Comment: making it non abstract will create an extra `thing` table with a one to one reference to `gadget` or `item`. Unless you have a clear need it, avoid non abstract inheritance in models. I can tell you I regretted it every single time when I decided to not make it abstract.

Comment: also if you are happy with the answer please accept it ;-)